# Converting .pdb to mysql

Tags: mysql, palm-os

I'm currently having some .pdb files which i believe it to be palm os database files which I am looking to convert them to mysql format for usage and manipulation .

Can such a conversion be done ?

Comment: Are you sure it is the right file? I found this on the microsoft website: A program database (PDB) file holds debugging and project state information that allows incremental linking of a debug configuration of your program.

Comment: Hi RV-10Builder , thanks for replying! Yes I'm sure of it. I've obtained the files off an android application which is using the .PDB files as a database (Which was puzzling me as well as I've never seen anyone used .pdb files but only sqlite). I've opened the .pdb files and it seems to be in a whole chunk of texts without any proper formatting. With that said , the app continues to display the  .pdb contents properly. So i'm thinking there must be a way which i can read those files properly too . Any ideas ?

Comment: @RV-10Builder, this should be a comment on the question, as it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Thanks, Inuyasha.  I am new here and getting adjusted to the way things are setup.

Comment: The PDB file format is documented in several places: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDB_(Palm_OS)#Structure_of_PDB_file and http://fileformats.archiveteam.org/wiki/Palm_OS_Database.